# Google Cloud ML Keras Image Classification Error 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-ml

Im trying to training a inception_InceptionResNetV2 in Google Cloud ML with keras and tensorflow Backend, but always get the following error:

```
master-replica-0
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code exec code in run_globals File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/cloud_trainer.py", line 136, in <module> train(args) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/cloud_trainer.py", line 114, in train class_weight='auto') File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2088, in fit_generator self._make_train_function() File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 990, in _make_train_function loss=self.total_loss) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 470, in get_updates self.updates.append(K.update(m, m_t)) File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 960, in update return tf.assign(x, new_x) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/state_ops.py", line 277, in assign return ref.assign(value) AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

The code I use:

```
  train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
      rotation_range=30,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True
  )
  test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      preprocessing_function=preprocess_input,
      rotation_range=30,
      width_shift_range=0.2,
      height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True
  )

  print("Test")
  os.system("mkdir pauls_tmp")
  os.system("gsutil -m cp -r " + args.train_dir + " pauls_tmp/")
  os.system("gsutil -m cp -r " + args.val_dir + " pauls_tmp/")

  train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
      "pauls_tmp/train/",
      target_size=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT),
      batch_size=batch_size,
    )

  validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
      "pauls_tmp/validation",
      target_size=(IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT),
      batch_size=batch_size,
    )
 # setup model
  model = InceptionResNetV2(weights=None, include_top=True, classes=nb_classes) #include_top=False excludes final FC layer
  model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

  print("Start Training")
  history_tl = model.fit
  history_tl = model.fit_generator(
     train_generator,
     epochs=nb_epoch,
     validation_data=validation_generator,
     class_weight='auto')
```

I use Keras 2.1.4.

When I run the code local everything works fine.

Do you have any pointers?

Best Regards,

Paul

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow are you using?

Comment: local i tried with 1.8.0, and 1.6.0 and in cloud ml i didnt specifiy the version. You know what the default version is?

Comment: I check again and Im using Tensorflow version 1.8.0 in cloud ml and runtime version 1.8

Comment: the error indicates you are using either an old keras or an old tensorflow version. Check which version you have at runtime by importing tensorflor as tf and then printing tf.__version__

Comment: Tensorflow Version 1.8.0 and Keras Version 2.1.6

Comment: Just to clarify: is Kerase Version 2.1.6 the version you are using in the cloud? How do you specify this version?

Comment: I tried it with different versions of keras and tensorflow in the cloud. The version I told you about was on my local maschine, but I also tried it with  the same version in cloud ml

Comment: The errors seem to be a mismatch in the libraries used, that's probably why you can run it locally and not on Cloud ML. Please edit your question adding all necessary steps to reproduce it, libraries used locally and on Cloud ML and the code used, so we can test it and find the root cause of your issue. Even it's not the same "RestNet" version you are using, I saw this [question](https://github.com/flyyufelix/cnn_finetune/issues/2) that says some versions for TF and Keras are not supported.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the feedback. I tried some other stuff but couldn't get it to work, so I gave up and used some other code entirerly

Answer (score 0):

In some place in your code you're calling tf.assign(t, value) where t is a Tensor and not a Variable.

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt explain why my code runs on my local maschine just fine and not in cloud ml, also I dont use tensorflow directly, I use keras.

Comment: From your stack trace this looks like it's in the momentum update code somewhere, probably Adam. Maybe another optimizer will work, and you should file a bug against keras?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Still same result with SGD as an Optimizier..

Comment: I think this needs to become an issue on github, with instructions to reproduce